# Why the customized .xlsm file works on One-Drive, but not on SharePoint?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created macroed .xlsm file with customized ribbon. File was located on SharePoint and moved back again after adding customUI as per below instruction:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file

The file works just fine from the Desktop and One-Drive, but crashes when I try to open it from SharePoint (Refresh recommended, new version is available on server) location.

Comment: i believe that macros doesnt work in sharepoint... only in local

Comment: I just added the ribbon customization - the macroes worked fine before.

Comment: When it crashes are you opening it on the Excel application, or in the browser.